# which mysql library should i use in php and why

Tags: php, mysql

I have been using php for quite a sometime now and encounter three different interfaces viz. `mysql_*, mysqli_* and PDO` to connecting with mysql database. What i am not able to understand is why to have so many interfaces for the same.. if one is better then which one?? or is it a matter of choice between select one or other. Does there exists any difference in performance and speed with each of the interfaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While mysql (procedural) and mysqli (OO) are MySQL client libraries, PDO is a data-access abstraction layer, it allows you to use different database drivers. An advantage of PDO is you could, theorically, change your database driver without rewriting your querying code.

I recommend you to check http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php where differences between those 3 libraries are briefly discussed.

Answer (score 1):

The MySQLi extension is a new & improved (hence the *i*) database driver, compared to MySQL.
With MySQLi you can take advantage of features such as prepared statements, as well as what fcingolani has said.

PDO is a data-access abstraction layer, which have many drivers such as MsSQL, MySQL and PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going really only with MySQL you should go with `MySQLi` as it's specific to MySQL and faster that the regular `MySQL`. If you're doing MySQL now but may be doing Postgree or any database in the future PDO abstracts your database logic from the actual database so should be your choice.

MySQLi is **slightly faster** on some operations that **PDO**.